# Azure b2c Custom email verification doesn't work

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, customization, azure-ad-b2c, email-verification

I have several days trying to customize the email verification of my project but it's been impossible to change anything.

I followed many times:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-mailjet

I uploaded the new custom policies **B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase** and **B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions** with all the changes described in the manual, but I still don't know why I can't even generate an application error and the default Microsoft email verification keeps working normally, is there any way to track what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the troubleshoot documentation about turning the B2C engine into developer mode and tracking the B2C engine itself.

There is a separate documentation and technical profiles explaining how to use application insights to track user behavior during user journeys. You can discover more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/analytics-with-application-insights): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/analytics-with-application-insights